# i'm trying to print the minimum mark in the record in the binary file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define etudian_num 400
struct etudiant{
char nom[10];
float moy;
int matricule;
};

void SaisirEtudiant(struct etudiant E,FILE *ficheierEtudiant){
ficheierEtudiant = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","wb");
char rep;
do {
   fseek(ficheierEtudiant, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Saisir Matricule de L etudiant: ");
    scanf("%i",&E.matricule);
    printf("Saisir nom etudiant a saisir: ");
    scanf("%s",&E.nom);
    printf("Saisir son Moyen: ");
    scanf("%f",&E.moy);
    fwrite (&E, sizeof(struct etudiant), 1,ficheierEtudiant);
    if(fwrite!=0){
        printf("\n\nEtudaint Ajouter avec succees !\n\n");
  }
  printf("Voulez Vouz Saisir un autre Etudiant (O,N): ");
  scanf(" %c",&rep);
  }while(toupper(rep)!='N');

fclose(ficheierEtudiant);

}

void AjoutEtudian(struct etudiant E,FILE *ficheierEtudiant){
ficheierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","ab+");
printf("Saisir Matricule de Nouveau Etudiant: ");
scanf("%i",&E.matricule);
printf("Saisir Nom de Nouveau Etudiant: ");
scanf("%s",&E.nom);
printf("Saisir Son Moyen: ");
scanf("%f",&E.moy);
fwrite (&E, sizeof(struct etudiant), 1,ficheierEtudiant);
printf("Saisir de nouveau Etudiant avec Success ! ");
fclose(ficheierEtudiant);
}







void AfficheListe(struct etudiant E, FILE* fichierEtudiant){
fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","r+");
while(fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant)){
printf("\nMatricule: %i | Nom Etudiant: %s| Moyen= %.2f \n",E.matricule,E.nom,E.moy);}
fclose(fichierEtudiant);

}


void ModifierEtudiant(struct etudiant E,FILE* fichierEtudiant){
fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","rb+");
int MatRecherche;
printf("Saisir Le Matricule de letudiant a modifier son Moyen: ");
scanf("%i",&MatRecherche);
float Moyenancianen=0.0;
float NouveauMoyen;
int p;
while(fread(&E,sizeof(E),1,fichierEtudiant)){

    if(E.matricule==MatRecherche){
    fseek(fichierEtudiant,-(long)sizeof(E),1);
        printf("Saisir Nouveau Moyen pour %s:",E.nom);
        scanf("%f",&NouveauMoyen);
        Moyenancianen=E.moy;
        E.moy=NouveauMoyen;
        fwrite (&E, sizeof(E), 1,fichierEtudiant);
        printf("\n\nMoyen Ancien = %.2f , Nouveau Moyen = %.2f\n\n",Moyenancianen,NouveauMoyen);
        break;
    }
}

fclose(fichierEtudiant);

}

void suprimList(struct etudiant E , FILE* fichierEtudiant){
fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","w");
printf("Contenu Supprime! ");
fclose(fichierEtudiant);
}

void min_moy(struct etudiant E , FILE* fichierEtudiant){
fichierEtudiant=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/TDTP/Ex1/Etudiant.dat","rb+");
float min=0.0;
int pos=0;
float T[30];
int LongeurTableau=0;
//Affectation de Moyenne dans un tableau T et Calcul de sa Taille
while(fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant)){
       T[LongeurTableau]=E.moy;
       LongeurTableau++;
        }
     //Determiner la position de Moyen le Plus Bas
    min=T[0];
   for(int j=0;j<LongeurTableau;j++){
     while(T[j]<min){
        pos=j;
        min=T[j];
     }
   }
   fseek(fichierEtudiant,0,pos);
   fread(&E,sizeof(struct etudiant),1,fichierEtudiant);
   printf("%s a eu la Moyenne Le Plus Bas avec un Moyen = %.2f",E.nom,E.moy);
}



void Menu(){
printf("Press: \n");
printf("\t\n1-Pour Ajouter un Nouveau List des Etudiant\n");
printf("\t\n2-pour Afficher Liste des Etudiant \n");
printf("\t\n3-pour Ajouter un Nouveau Etudiant \n");
printf("\t\n4-pour Modifier Moyen d un EtudainT\n");
printf("\t\n5-pour Afficher Liste de Menu\n");
printf("\t\n6-pour Supprimer La liste\n");
printf("\t\n7-pour Avoir Le minimum Moyenne: \n");
printf("\t\n8-Pour Quitter \n");
}









int main()
{ printf("\t\t***************************Programme de Gestion des Etudiants***************************\n\n\n\n");
   FILE *fichierEtudiant;
    struct etudiant E;
    float NouveauMoyen;
    int choice;
    int num;
    int quit=0;
    Menu();
    while(quit==0){
        printf("\nSaisir Votre Choix: ");
        scanf(" %d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            SaisirEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 2:
            AfficheListe(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 3:
            AjoutEtudian(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;

        case 4:

            ModifierEtudiant(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 5:
            Menu();
            break;
        case 6:
            suprimList(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 7:
            min_moy(E,fichierEtudiant);
            break;
        case 8:
            quit =1;
            printf("\n\nA bientot.....\n\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }



//Souid_Ayoub

}
```

the program is about student stuff it outputs their marks , their name etc... i m trying to find out which of the student got the minimum Mark it works when i found position of the student by creating an float array and found position of the minimum number in the array then tried to point using this position and read the name and the mark of the student looks like it didn't work the method name(min_moy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `fseek` incorrectly. This code

```
fseek(fichierEtudiant,0,pos);
```

will **not** move the file position to the `pos` record.

The function prototype is:

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

(from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)

So you rather need something like:

```
fseek(fichierEtudiant, pos * sizeof(struct etudiant), SEEK_SET);
```

However, since you already have read all records once why not store them completely in the array instead of just storing the a single float member. Seeking and rereading a single record will perform pretty bad.

BTW: This code

```
 while(T[j]<min){
    pos=j;
    min=T[j];
 }
```

seems pretty strange. It can be replaced by:

```
 if (T[j]<min){
    pos=j;
    min=T[j];
 }
```

Comment: thanks you man <3 however can you explay the part (pos*sizeof(etudiant))?